# How to solve this error: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote the following code in Oracle and got ERROR:date format picture ends before converting entire input string

```
to_date(substr(AE1.aestdtc_001_dts, 1, 10),'YYYY/MM/DD') <to_date(substr(AE2.AEENDTC_001_DTS,1, 10),'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

AEENDTC_001_DTS is like 2020-05-13T10:14

Comment: Is `AEENDTC_001_DTS` column is a date datatype in your table? It is working. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f34bb8b8a0b19f24a56b676f95abcaf2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format mask is off.  Consider this version:

```
TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AE1.aestdtc_001_dts, 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD') < 
    TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AE2.AEENDTC_001_DTS, 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Note that you could also have used `TO_TIMESTAMP`, and included the time portion:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(AE1.aestdtc_001_dts, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI') < 
    TO_TIMESTAMP(AE2.AEENDTC_001_DTS, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI')
```

In this particular case, assuming your text timestamps are fixed width, actually *could* have just compared the text directly:

```
AE1.aestdtc_001_dts < AE2.AEENDTC_001_DTS
```

But note that it is not ideal to store timestamps/dates as text in your Oracle database, use a proper date/timestamp column instead.

Comment: I tried  'YYYY-MM-DD', but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Yes, it does work.  [See the demo](https://rextester.com/BXFEF71458).

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the values as strings, you can do the comparison using strings:

```
substr(AE1.aestdtc_001_dts, 1, 10) < substr(AE2.AEENDTC_001_DTS, 1, 10)
```

You *should* be using `date`/`timestamp` to store these values.  However you have chosen a good string format for comparisons.  So, there is no reason to convert to a `date` or `timestamp`.